# Sorting numbers of an array in descending order

Tags: c++, sorting

I have an array of 16 numbers that i need to sort in descending order, I tried sorting them this way but can't seem to make it work.

**Note : I have to program an algorithm so i can't use any special functions :(**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i, temp1, temp2;
    int string2[16] = { 0, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 6, 2, 6, 89, 21, 32, 31, 5, 32, 12 };
    _Bool check = 1;

    while (check) {
        temp1 = string2[i];
        temp2 = string2[i + 1];
        if (temp1 < temp2) {
            string2[i + 1] = temp1;
            string2[i] = temp2;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
            if (i = 15) {
                check = !check;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I realize that this is pretty basic stuff for most of you but any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: "What" doesn't work? Please specify the problem clearly in the post. "cant seem to make it work" is really vague.

Comment: There are approximately fifty zillion examples of sorting available online and in the literature.

Comment: `_Bool` is an identifier reserved to the language implementation. Did you use it intentionally?

Comment: BTW: `_Bool` is a strange thing to see in a C++ program (your book certainly didn't mention it), and "string2" is a very odd name for an array of integers.

Comment: just an hint: what's the starting value of `i`? it should be zero, right? and then what @molbdnilo said

Comment: is this a `c++` question or a `c` one? It looks more like c, since you're using the c headers and `_Bool`.

Comment: Heed thy warnings. More specifically, compile with maximum warning level (-Wall with gcc, /W4 with MSVC) and **eliminate or understand the warnings.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're a few problems:

1. `_Bool` is a strange thing to use in C++ (maybe this question intended for C?)
2. You didn't initialize `i`. This is called an [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). This may or may not work, depends on the computer, but it's never good to have something like that in your program.
3. `(i=15)` is an assignment. Use `i==15` for comparison, as `==` is the [comparison operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) for "equal to".

Reviewed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 0,temp1,temp2; //i should be initialized
    int string2[16] = {0,4,2,5,1,5,6,2,6,89,21,32,31,5,32,12};
    bool check=1;

    while(check)
    {
        temp1=string2[i];
        temp2=string2[i+1];

        if(temp1<temp2)
        {
            string2[i+1]=temp1;
            string2[i]=temp2;
            i=0;
        }

        else
        {
            i++;
            if(i==15) { check=!check; } // = -> ==
        }
    }

    //if this is intended for C, you can ignore this bit, or use printf
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) { std::cout << string2[i] << " ";}
}
```

Output: `89 32 32 31 21 12 6 6 5 5 5 4 2 2 1 0`

A few more aesthetic notes:

- If you use indentation (tabs and/or space), be consistent. Others may have a hard time understanding your code, although it doesn't matter when the program compile (to anyone questioning, this is before he re-indented the code).
- `string2` is an irregular name of an `int` array. Again, it could cause confusion. A reading : https://1c-dn.com/library/rules_of_naming_variables/

Comment: Seems like the i=15 was the problem! Thank you!

Comment: no! all of those points were problems (2 and 3 at least). This is exactly why I think explain things and also give the working code is never a good instructive thing to do. The explanation part should be enough.

Comment: @Federico Hmm, maybe you're right. I'll try to do that next time.

Comment: @silverfox just to clarify, it was not a negative comment about your answer, it's clear and complete. But I assume he copy/pasted this code => "it works" => cool! next time i'll be careful about == inside `if`s. And (for some reason) he lost the importance of initialization of variables.

Comment: @Federico of course, I understand, no need to worry :P I'll take that into consideration next time is all I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `std::sort` with `std::greater<int>()` parameter:
`std::sort(std::begin(string2), std::end(string2), std::greater<int>());`
don't invent a bicycle except you need to learn something or you know the way how to optimize your case.